# Why am I not able to use SearchEngine() from uszipcodes to get city names?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, zipcode

I have a pd dataframe with zipcodes for customers and I am trying to add a new row into the dataframe that containts city obtained from uszipcodes using SearchEngine()

```
!pip install uszipcode
from uszipcode import SearchEngine, SimpleZipcode
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(dataset)

data['City_Name'] = np.nan
search = SearchEngine()
for i in data['ZIPCode']:
    data['City_Name'] = search.by_zipcode(i).city
```

I get this error:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [35], in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 search = SearchEngine()
> 2 for i in data['ZIPCode']:
> 3     #city = search.by_zipcode(i).city
> 4     SearchEngine().by_zipcode(i).city
> 
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'city'
```

When trying this just to test:

```
city = search.by_zipcode(75024).city
```

It works fine.

Not sure what's going on, any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit:
I figured out that it was failing at ZIP 92717, and proceeded to drop that row and run the same code again. now I'm getting this error.

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError             Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [96], in <cell line: 4>()
>       2 search = SearchEngine()
>       3 num = 0
> ----> 4 for i in data['ZIPCode']:
>       5     data['City_Name'] = search.by_zipcode(i).city
> 
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` that you're getting?

Comment: The value of i is the zip codes as integers.

Comment: No, I'm asking what is the specific value of `i` when the code breaks? Just `print(i)` right before you call the search engine. One of the reasons you'll get that error is if you pass an invalid ZIP code.

Comment: error says that some result for some row is None

Comment: Just tried printing i in the loop and it seems to work until it hits a certain row, it must be that the specific zipcode in that row is not in the database. Is there any way to get the function to skip over rows that may not have results and keep going?

Comment: What is that ZIP code? FYI, they start at `00501` and go to `99950`, so that could be part of a simple validation scheme to run on your df before applying this function. It may also be that the ZIP code simply doesn't exist.

Comment: I've figured it out! uszipcodes seemed to be missing data for about 5 zipcodes in my dataset, when I manually entered those the rest worked. Thanks for your help again!